# elasticsearch equivalent of join

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search and I'm trying to figure out how to do the equivalent of a SQL join.  Here are my 2 mappings:

```
{
     "home_panel": {
          "mappings": {
               "levis": {
               "properties": {
               "created_at": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "current": {
                    "type": "string"
               },
               "event_uuid": {
                    "type": "string"
               },
               "panels": {
                    "properties": {
                                   "action": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                   },
                                   "heightratio": {
                                        "type": "double"
                                   },
                                   "type": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                   },
                                   "url": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                   },
                                   "videourl": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                   }
                              }
                         },
                         "status": {
                              "type": "string"
                         },
                         "updated_at": {
                              "type": "date",
                              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                         },
                         "uuid": {
                              "type": "string"
                         }
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}
```

And:

```
{
    "event": {
        "mappings": {
            "levis": {
                "properties": {
                    "date": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    },
                    "event_uuid": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ticketmaster_game_event_name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ticketmaster_parking_event_name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "time": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd ideally like to do something like `select * from HomePanel InnerJoin Event On home_panel.event_uuid = event.event_uuid` so I can see the event in the home panel object. I'm not clear how to do this in elastic search. Is this even possible?

Comment: You need to rethink your design or use application-side joins: [http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Join query" in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708689/join-query-in-elasticsearch)