# "Join query" in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say we have two index types: members and restaurants. Both contain city attribute.

I want to filter members (e.g. by name) and would like to include list of restaurant names from the members' hometown/city in the results.

Is it possible to do this using just one ES query? I guess it should be similar to DB join.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch "Join" tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255852/elasticsearch-join-tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES doesn't have the concepts of joins. This is due to it being an index rather than a relational database. Your best best to make two calls. One to get the member's documents, then another to get the restaurants.

Unless you have odd circumstances, this should still be very efficient.