# Elasticsearch "Join" tables

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch, join, nosql

I need to do "Join" between 2 indexes (tables) and preform a check on specific field on documents that exists in both indexes.

I want to add condition like "dateExpiry" below, but I get an error. Is it possible to join 2 or more indexes?

```
GET cache-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "query": {
            "terms": {
              "TagId": {
                "index": "domain_block-2016.06",
                "type": "cBlock",
                "id": "57692ef6ae8c50f67e8b45",
                "path": "TagId",
               "range" : {
               "dateExpiry" : {
                   "gte" :  "20160705T12:00:00"
               }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Elasticsearch doesn't do classic "join"s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join query in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611049/join-query-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1):

Filters within a [Terms Query Lookup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-terms-query.html) are currently not supported. However, Elasticsearch has some great documentation on joins / relationships [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/relations.html).

Your best bet may be to run two queries against Elasticsearch - one to fetch the list of TagIds, then another that includes the list as an exclusion clause.