# Join documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have these product documents:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "http://localhost:9200/test/_bulk?pretty" -d'
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"product"}}
{"id":"1", "price": "260" }
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"product"}}
{"id":"2", "price": "420" }
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"product"}}
{"id":"3", "price": "250" }
```

And these discount documents:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "http://localhost:9200/test/_bulk?pretty" -d'
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"discount"}}
{"product_id":"1", "group_id": 12, "percent": "50" }
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"discount"}}
{"product_id":"1", "group_id": 15, "percent": "20" }
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"discount"}}
{"product_id":"3", "group_id": 12, "percent": "10" }
```

I need to join these two documents via the `product_id` and `group_id` key.

In the mysql database would look like this:

```
SELECT p.id, IF(d.percent > 0, p.price - (d.percent*p.price/100), p.price) price 
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN discount d ON p.id=d.product_id AND d.group_id=12
WHERE IF(d.percent > 0, p.price - (d.percent*p.price/100), p.price) < 210
```

The result of that query will be only one row:

```
id => 1
price => 130
```

Is it possible to do in elasticsearch?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915428/how-to-setup-elasticsearch-index-structure-with-multiple-entity-bindings/36982705#36982705

Comment: Elasticsearch does not do joins between indices and supporting multiple types per index has been deprecated and should produce an error in recent versions of Elasticsearch. You might be able to denormalize discounts into the products and do it that way, though. For that, look into using nested queries and aggregations.

Comment: ok, thank you. I think that I know how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Join query" in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708689/join-query-in-elasticsearch)